# How Do you Build A GUI shell for DOS?

Tags: shell, operating-system

I would like to build a GUI shell for DOS so I can make a shell operating system like windows. I know this may sound stupid, but I'm just a beginner looking for a challenge. I was thinking something along the lines of Dream16OS but a little better looking. Also is it possible to make this in Visual Basic for DOS or Visual Basic 1 or any recent visual Basic? You can download Download from Geek Basic . webs . com

Also, I have started a project similar to this and could really use some guidance, so please check it out and post in the forum. Thanks Link Below
http://boss-basicoperatingsystemsimulation.yolasite.com/

Comment: Why not use something like DirectFB?  It has a modern and supported operating system underneath.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for alot of pain. DOS doesn't give you any facilities for drawing windows, handling events and your memory is extremely limited.

Those of us old enough to remember near and far pointers will tell you it is a huge pain in the rear.

You can do what old dos games did and use a dos extender. This will give you a nice flat address space at least.

You might be able to find some old [windowing toolkits](http://utenti.multimania.it/dcg/alfagui.html) 
that will let you draw windows in all the glory of 640x480.

You can probably use the DOS version of visual basic, but you will end up with windows that look like [your bios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMicrosoft_Visual_Basic_for_MS-DOS_%28Professional_Edition_Version1.00%29.png) (remember dosshell.exe?)

Comment: A full-blown event-driven, overlapping capable, CUA compliant windowing kit is a bit of code, but it's not that terrible to make something "hobby quality" that works.  With VESA standard video modes, it's pretty easy to go higher-res too.  My old XT eventually had more video RAM than system RAM and could run 1280x1024!